# Randomize content search web part results

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am attempting to randomize search results from a content search web part on an o365 sharepoint farm.

The end goal is to have a randomized employee spotlight web part.  So I cannot use a list column to randomize, it needs to come from the web part only.

I have seen this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938031%28v=office.15%29.aspx#SP15_Sort_search_results_in_random_order

using this parameter I can get a rest url to randomize results:

http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='home'&sortlist='[random:seed=5432]:ascending

The problem is I cannot get [random:seed=5432] to work in the web part.  I tried adding it as a dynamic sorting rule but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.